# Load .env file in clojure

Tags: clojure, configuration, environment-variables, env

Is there any recommended way to load configuration inside a `.env` file in clojure?

I've found https://github.com/rentpath/clj-dotenv and https://github.com/jackmorrill/dotenv which seemed to do what I want, but both of them are not available on clojars.org anymore with github activity being very low.

There also is https://github.com/weavejester/environ/ but I have not quite gotten my head around how to use it, since the `project.clj` is tracked inside my git repository and my configuration (in dev also) contains potentially sensible information such as API tokens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic approach is to edn/read an .edn file that contains a map of configuration. You don't need a library to do this. You just need to manage the file (don't check it in if it contains passwords, but do deploy it to where it needs to go).

Environ is great for getting values from the environment, but how you get them into your environment is up to you. One way would be source an env file before launching your application.

This library https://github.com/outpace/config can help for more complicated needs. It allows you to pull configuration from many different sources (files, environment, or specify something else) in different formats (edn/string).

Ultimately you have to decide where you want configuration to be and how it will get there, both of which are not directly something you do from your Clojure project, but are instead deployment concerns. Feel free to add more specifics if this is missing your needs.